# Highcharts pie legend clipped off

Tags: highcharts

When the Pie chart legend is paginated, the legend items on the first line of the legend are not fully displayed, it is clipped off

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arjunbadarinath/zR6X7/2/) for it, with the code here:

```
function(){
    $('#container').highcharts({
       credits:{
          enabled:false
       },
       legend:{
          itemStyle:{
             fontFamily:'Arial',
             fontSize:'10pt'
          },
          maxHeight:55,
       },
       tooltip:{
          style:{
             fontFamily:'Arial',
             fontSize:'10pt'
          }
       },
       title:{
          style:{
             color:'#000000',
             fontFamily:'Arial'
          },
          text:'Pie legend problem',
          margin:50
       },
       chart:{
          renderTo:'container'
       },
       series:[
          {
             name:'Incident',
             type:'pie',
             data:[
                {
                   name:'Nadia Wilshire',
                   y:49,
                   color:'#73a8f0'
                },
                {
                   name:'ITIL User',
                   y:15,
                   color:'#318047'
                },
                {
                   name:'David Luie',
                   y:9,
                   color:'#f5c533',
                },
                {
                   name:'Don Godfire',
                   y:7,
                   color:'#004789',
                },
                {
                   name:'Bethline Angleen',
                   y:5,
                   color:'#f18320',
                },
                {
                   name:'Howard Johnwind',
                   y:3,
                   color:'#8f5699',
                },
                {
                   name:'Luke Smith',
                   y:3,
                   color:'#1e90ff',
                },
                {
                   name:'(empty)',
                   y:2,
                   color:'#3ed662',
                },
                {
                   name:'(empty2)',
                   y:2,
                   color:'#3ed662',
                },
                {
                   name:'(empty3)',
                   y:2,
                   color:'#3ed662',
                },
                {
                   name:'(empty4)',
                   y:2,
                   color:'#3ed662',
                },
             ]
          }
       ],
       exporting:{
          enabled:true
       },
       plotOptions:{
          pie:{
             cursor:'pointer',
             size:'95%',
             dataLabels:{
                enabled:false
             },
             showInLegend:true,
             tooltip:{
                pointFormat:'<b>{point.y}</b>'
             }
          }
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Adjust fontsize by **px** and use maxHeight accordingly.

```
legend:{
  itemStyle:{
    fontFamily:'Arial',
    fontSize:'13px'
},
maxHeight:58
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Ly3Zr/

Comment: I'm not sure if I agree with this. The font size is a platform wide configuration, we want the data visualization (the charts) also to use the same font size and have no control over it. Highcharts should intelligently figure out and render the legend accordingly.